# Unable to set APK meta-data using google API dot net client

Tags: android, google-api-dotnet-client, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I have been able to **successfully upload** my APK to the google play developer console using C# code and the [nuget google android publisher api client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3/).

I have also been able to **successfully update** the following metadata for my app in the google play store using the [client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3/):

- title
- short description
- full description
- release track (e.g. "alpha")
- release notes
- release name
- status (e.g. "draft")
- version code
- images (icon, phone screenshots, tablet screenshots, feature graphic)
- contact email
- contact phone
- contact website

However I have been **unable** to update the following metadata using the [client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3/):

- applicaton type
- category
- privacy policy URL
- content rating parameters
- content rating email
- price setting (free or paid)
- available countries
- primarily child-directed (yes/no)
- contains ads (yes/no)
- marketing opt-out
- content guidelines
- US export laws

I have searched the [google docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/get_started) extensively but been unable to find out to update these properties thourgh the [client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3/).

Is it possible to update these properties thourgh the [client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.AndroidPublisher.v3/), and if so how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to alter these through an API. All of these properties are legal obligations / declarations you make as an app developer. This means they have to be done by a human, and not through an API.

However, this should not be too onerous, as they only have to be done once per app. When you update your app, you can do it through the API.